# C# Dapper UPPER functions

Tags: dapper

I'm using Dapper C# .Net Core 6.0 MVC

Query ;

```
 var query = $"SELECT d.Id,d.CityId,d.CountryId,UPPER(d.Name) FROM District as d INNER JOIN City as c ON d.CityId = c.Id Where c.Id={Convert.ToInt32(id)}";
 var result = conn.Query<CityDto>(query).ToList();
```

Data gets  but value of d.Name is null

It works when I execute it in SQL Server

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper cares about column names, and `UPPER(d.Name)` is an anonymous column; consider using `as` to alias the column:

```cs
var result = conn.Query<CityDto>(@"
SELECT d.Id, d.CityId, d.CountryId, UPPER(d.Name) as [Name]
FROM District as d
INNER JOIN City as c ON d.CityId = c.Id
Where c.Id=@id", new { id }).AsList();
```

Note I also fixed the parameter usage.

Comment: @AhmetPoyrazAkçal, why wouldn't you mark your replied questions as answered. Please do that.

Comment: you are right i am correcting